# ARM Cortex M0+: How to use "Branch if Carry" instructions in C-code?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

I have some C code that processes data bit-by-bit. Simplified example:

```
// input data, assume this is initialized
uint32_t data[len];

for (uint32_t idx=0; idx<len; idx++)
{
    uint32_t tmp = data[idx];
    
    // iterate over all bits
    for (uint8_t pos=0; pos<32; pos++)
    {
        if (tmp & 0b1)
        {
            // some code
        }
    
        tmp = tmp >> 1;
    }
}
```

In my application `len` is relatively large, so I'd like to optimize the inner loop as highly as possible. The `// some code` section is small and already heavily optimized.

I'm using an ARM Cortex M0+ MCU which has an instruction to branch if the carry bit is set (see [cortex-m0+ manual](https://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/arm/cortex_m0p/r0p0/dui0662a_cortex_m0p_r0p0_dgug.pdf#page=45), page 45). Conviniently shifting bits places the LSB (or MSB) into the carry flag, so in theory it can branch without the comparison like this:

```
// input data, assume this is initialized
uint32_t data[len];

for (uint32_t idx=0; idx<len; idx++)
{
    uint32_t tmp = data[idx];

    // iterate over all bits
    for (uint8_t pos=0; pos<32; pos++)
    {
        tmp = tmp >> 1;

        if ( CARRY_SET )
        {
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to archive this with C code and/or inline Assembler? Ideally I'd like to keep the `// come code` in C for simplicity and better readability.

---

Edit 1: I've tested this code on <strike>GCC 5.4</strike> GCC 6.3 with -O1, -O2 and -03. For every setting it generates the following assembly code (note the dedicated `tst` instruction I try to get rig of):

```
        if (data & 0b1)             
00000218   movs r3, #1       
0000021A   tst  r3, r6       
0000021C   beq  #4
```

---

Edit 2: minimal reproducable example. I'm writing the code in Atmel Studio 7 (because it's intended for a MCU) and inspect the values int the build-in debugger. If you use a different enviroment, you may need to add som IO code:

```
int main(void)
{
    uint32_t tmp = 0x12345678;
    volatile uint8_t bits = 0;  // volatile needed in this example to prevent compiler from optimizing away all code.

    // iterate over all bits
    for (uint8_t pos=0; pos<32; pos++)
    {
        if (tmp & 1)
        {
            bits++;    // the real code isn't popcount.  Some compilers may transform this example loop into a different popcount algorithm if bits wasn't volatile.
        }
        tmp = tmp >> 1;
    }

    // read bits here with debugger
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: Which compiler and which optimization settings do you use? This sounds like something your compiler should do for you automatically.

Comment: Good question. Unfortunatly the compiler doesn't optimize this, I've updated the post with this info.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] I can compile as is without having to guess what the remaining code looks like.

Comment: Trying to optimize while mixing C code and assembly is difficult, because you keep pushing the compiler around by inserting inline assembly, and you often end up fighting the compiler. In these cases, it is best to just write the entire subroutine, or at least the key loop, in assembly.

Comment: I've never seen gcc use the fact that (some) shifts (on some architectures, mostly x86[_64] and ARM32) can set a flag. If gcc doesn't do it on x86 (where gcc codegen is mostly excellent), it *probably* won't do it on ARM32 (where gcc codegen is mostly terrible, and which is getting pretty obsolete, considering what a terrible architecture ARM32 is) any time soon. Also, your obsolete gcc probably doesn't have asm flags, because it's ancient and older than gcc6.

Comment: @fuz: example added

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: Re-arangement can be an issue, but I think there are special compiler instructions to prevent that. Serial bit operations on MCUs are quite common, so I hoped somebody else has optimized this before.

Comment: Note that GCC 5.4 has been release 5 year ago, newer version might optimize the code better although this is a bit hard on such a processor with so few features/instructions. Note also that unrolling may help to reduce the number of instructions and use a and rather than a shift.

Comment: @nqtronix: Rearranging one instructions is just one issue. Using inline assembly can also interfere with which registers the compiler uses and how it uses them, with which instructions it generates for the other code, and more. The compiler generally cannot “see” the semantics of the inline assembly and so cannot handle it well when optimizing the code around it. Further, if you do manage to reach some accord with the compiler and generate code you like, that may break in future versions of the compiler.

Comment: If your gcc was less prehistoric, you could write this in [extended asm](https://godbolt.org/z/GcEYhn3PW). Unfortunately, unlike for x86 gcc (where asm flags have been supported since gcc6), ARM gcc only supports this feature since gcc10.

Comment: @ericpostpischill I have done some inline assembly on the AVR8 architecture before. It is possible to let the compiler assign registers for the ASM code, or explicitly tell the compiler which registers you have used. In general this works well, and even branching outside the ASM code should work fine, but I'm lacking the experience with the cortex-m0 to gurantee that it will always work.

Comment: Look for some header called "intrinsic" or so. It might include rotating functions that will be optimized into few assembly lines.

Comment: @thebusybee yeah, there are a few macros for rotation and even (read) access of the APSR register (which includes the carry bit), but there are no conditional pre-defines

Comment: arm is a much better instruction set than x86.  and gcc has gotten worse every year yes,  gcc 5.x is one of the better ones for code produced, it has gone down hill since.  It  is likely because you asked for an and that used an and.  I wouldnt say this is a missed optimization necessarily.   you should try godbolt and aim at many versions and architectures.  There are other ways to skin this cat that are efficient and not needing to use the specific optimization you desire.   making the value volatile is not helping for exmaple.

Comment: @old_timer when optimizing I always keep the C code, the optimisation can be enabled with a #define. As the comment says `volatile` is only used in the example for testing, not im my final code.

Comment: You might look into `__builtin_add_overflow` and such. Even if you don't really want an add, it may be worth it for better branching (but do check!). Also, I imagine that your `tmp >> 1` in a loop might actually pessmize things compared to doing a full shift-and-mask every iteration. Keep in mind what instructions have dependencies on others (I know that's not as big a deal on ARM as on x86, but even on hardware where it doesn't matter at all, it still matters in the compiler).

Comment: Note that your particular example is population count, and gcc provides a `__builtin_popcount` that will give you an optimized version, or a dedicated instruction on machines that have them.

Comment: I strongly doubt that what you are trying to achieve could yield a substantial improvement. Usually, the choices made by the optimizing compiler are excellent, and your "some code" section might very well have a significant cost that hides any side improvement. Unfortunately, you give all information except that opaque "some code", and you may be asking an XY question.

Comment: @yvesdaoust In C there is no way to explicitly use the shifted bit as a branch condition, and the compiler is not smart enough to do that optimization itself. My solution (see below) does not modify any registers, so the normal function of the compiler is not impacted. The "some code" section is irrelevant for the question and left out for clarity (of what my question is) and licensing reasons.

Comment: I don't believe that "some code" is irrelevant and I bet that your micro-optimization is useless.

Comment: @yvesdaost I *pysically* measured the execution time on the target MCU and yes, with my optimisation it's faster - independent of whatever you believe :P Granted, it may not be for some use cases, but IF somebody searches for something similiar they'll hopefully find my post, implement it for their application and compare benchmarks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not find an "easy" solution, so I had to write my short algorithm in assembler. This is what the demo code looks like:

```
// assume these values as initialized
uint32_t data[len];     // input data bit stream
uint32_t out;           // algorithm input + output
uint32_t in;            // algorithm input (value never written in asm)

for (uint32_t idx=0; idx<len; idx++)
{
    uint32_t tmp = data[idx];
    
    // iterate over all bits
    for (uint8_t pos=0; pos<32; pos++)
    {
        // use optimized code only on supported devices
        #if defined(__CORTEX_M) && (__CORTEX_M <= 4)
        asm volatile  // doesn't need to be volatile if you use the result
        (
            "LSR    %[tmp], %[tmp], #1" "\n\t"  // shift data by one. LSB is now in carry
            "BCC    END_%="             "\n\t"  // branch if carry clear (LSB was not set)
            
            /* your code here */        "\n\t"
        
            "END_%=:"                   "\n\t"  // label only, doesn't generate any instructions
        
            : [tmp]"+l"(tmp), [out]"+l"(out)    // out; l = register 0..7 = general purpose registers
            : [in]"l"(in)                       // in;
            : "cc"                              // clobbers: "cc" = CPU status flags have changed
                               // Add any other registers you use as temporaries, or use dummy output operands to let the compiler pick registers.
        );
        #else
        if (tmp & 0b1)
        {
            // some code
        }
        tmp = tmp >> 1;
        #endif
    }
}
```

For your application, add your assembly code at the marked location, and feed in data from the C function with the registers. Keep in mind that in Thumb mode, many instructions can only use 8 of the 16 general purpose registers, so you can't pass more values than that.

Inline assembly is very easy to get wrong in subtle ways that appear to work but can break after inlining into different surrounding code.  (For example, forgetting to declare a clobber.)  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm unless you need to (including for performance), but if so make sure you check the docs (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info).

Note that technically the correct shift instruction is `LSRS` (with an `s` suffix to set flags). *However* on GCC 6.3 + GAS writing `lsrs` in the asm code will cause an error assembling in thumb mode, but if you write `lsr` it assembles successfully into an `lsrs` instruction.  (In ARM mode, which Cortex-M doesn't support, `lsr` and `lsrs` both assemble to separate instructions as expected.)

---

Although I can not share my application code, I can tell you how much speedup this change had:

|  | -O1 | -O2 | -O3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| original | 812us | 780us | 780us |
| w/ asm | 748us | 686us | 716us |
| w/ asm + some loop unrolling | 732us | 606us | 648us |

So with my the ASM code and -O2 instead of -O1 I get a speedup of 15% and with additional loop unrolling I got a speedup of 25%.

Placing the function in RAM with `__attribute__ ((section(".ramfunc")))` yields another 1% improvement. (Make sure to test this on your device, some MCUs have awful flash cache miss penalties.)

See old_timer's answer below for more general purpose optimizations.

Comment: GAS assembles `lsrs` in ARM mode, e.g. with `gcc -mcpu=cortex-a15 -marm`.  https://godbolt.org/z/Ws1Y966e8 It's weird it doesn't accept it in Thumb mode.

Comment: `#if defined(__CORTEX_M) && (__CORTEX_M <= 4)` seems oddly specific, unless the gcc or clang for some reason do a better job for other ARM devices.  `ifdef __ARM__` should work.  Or possibly also check for thumb mode, if your asm won't assemble (and work correctly) in ARM mode.

Comment: @petercordes Well, if compiled in ARM mode the `LSR` instruction is incorrect and would not work. Afaik all M4 or less do only support thumb mode and thus be valid devices. When working with assembler code I generally prefer to be more restrictive than needed and leave a comment for the next developer: "might work on other devices, but please test first"

Comment: Right, if there's no way to actually get GAS or clang to accept `lsrs`, then you would need to check for Thumb mode, like I said.

Answer (score 3):

If you have specific code you want then...you just write it.  Start with the compiled code and hand optimize as desired.  The compiler cannot read your mind.

gcc 5.x.x is where gnu peaked as far as code output, it has gone down hill since. but that does not mean that version is always better than the newer versions.  godbolt or just having various ones installed on your computer can help if you are trying to get the compiler to do the work for you.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int tmp )
{
    unsigned int bits;
    bits=0;
    for (unsigned char pos=0; pos<32; pos++)
    {
        if (tmp & 1)
        {
            bits++;
        }
        tmp = tmp >> 1;
    }
    return(bits);
}
```

with bits as a 32 bit

Disassembly of section .text:

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   0002        movs    r2, r0
   2:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
   4:   2320        movs    r3, #32
   6:   2000        movs    r0, #0
   8:   2401        movs    r4, #1
   a:   0021        movs    r1, r4
   c:   3b01        subs    r3, #1
   e:   4011        ands    r1, r2
  10:   b2db        uxtb    r3, r3
  12:   1840        adds    r0, r0, r1
  14:   0852        lsrs    r2, r2, #1
  16:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
  18:   d1f7        bne.n   a <fun+0xa>
  1a:   bd10        pop {r4, pc}
```

r4 is set one time outside the loop

with bits as an 8 bit value

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   0002        movs    r2, r0
   2:   2320        movs    r3, #32
   4:   2000        movs    r0, #0
   6:   2101        movs    r1, #1
   8:   4211        tst r1, r2
   a:   d001        beq.n   10 <fun+0x10>
   c:   3001        adds    r0, #1
   e:   b2c0        uxtb    r0, r0
  10:   3b01        subs    r3, #1
  12:   b2db        uxtb    r3, r3
  14:   0852        lsrs    r2, r2, #1
  16:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
  18:   d1f6        bne.n   8 <fun+0x8>
  1a:   4770        bx  lr
```

r1 is set to 1 outside the loop.  this one is less efficient as it has to do the utxb every loop.

naturally you would never want to use a char for a loop variable like that (nor for that counter), you want a register sized variable unless you need one larger than register sized and the you have to just incur the cost.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int tmp )
{
    unsigned int bits;
    bits=0;
    for (unsigned int pos=0; pos<32; pos++)
    {
        if (tmp & 1)
        {
            bits++;
        }
        tmp = tmp >> 1;
    }
    return(bits);
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   0003        movs    r3, r0
   2:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
   4:   2220        movs    r2, #32
   6:   2000        movs    r0, #0
   8:   2401        movs    r4, #1
   a:   0021        movs    r1, r4
   c:   3a01        subs    r2, #1
   e:   4019        ands    r1, r3
  10:   1840        adds    r0, r0, r1
  12:   085b        lsrs    r3, r3, #1
  14:   2a00        cmp r2, #0
  16:   d1f8        bne.n   a <fun+0xa>
  18:   bd10        pop {r4, pc}
```

that is a bit better

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int tmp )
{
    unsigned int bits;
    bits=0;
    for (unsigned int pos=0x80000000; pos; pos>>=1)
    {
        if (tmp & pos)
        {
            bits++;
        }
    }
    return(bits);
}
```

worse interestingly

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int tmp )
{
    unsigned int bits;
    bits=0;
    for (unsigned int pos=0x1; pos; pos<<=1)
    {
        if (tmp & pos)
        {
            bits++;
        }
    }
    return(bits);
}
```

not any better with this compiler.

When maybe you were looking for something like this

```
push {r4,lr}
mov r1,#0
mov r2,#1
mov r3,#32
top:
movs r4,r0
ands r4,r2
adds r1,r4
lsrs r0,r0,#1
subs r3,#1
bne top
mov r0,r1
pop {r4,pc}
```

For bit counting, but bit counting leads to some of this optimization (no need for a branch)

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int tmp, unsigned int bits )
{
    for (unsigned int pos=0; pos<32; pos++)
    {
        if (tmp & 1)
        {
            bits<<=2;
        }
        tmp >>= 1;
    }
    return(bits);
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   0003        movs    r3, r0
   2:   2220        movs    r2, #32
   4:   0008        movs    r0, r1
   6:   2101        movs    r1, #1
   8:   4219        tst r1, r3
   a:   d000        beq.n   e <fun+0xe>
   c:   0080        lsls    r0, r0, #2
   e:   3a01        subs    r2, #1
  10:   085b        lsrs    r3, r3, #1
  12:   2a00        cmp r2, #0
  14:   d1f8        bne.n   8 <fun+0x8>
  16:   4770        bx  lr
```

mov r1,#1 is still outside the loop.  The compiler was told to do an and and it is doing an and and maybe there is no coded optimization around the corner case of and 1 with a shift right later.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int tmp, unsigned int bits )
{
    for (unsigned int pos=0; pos<32; pos++)
    {
        tmp >>= 1;
        if (tmp & 1)
        {
            bits<<=2;
        }
    }
    return(bits);
}
```

This is obviously NOT functionally the same, but the compiler still uses an and (tst) here.

Would need to go look at the gcc sources to see when if ever it produces a bcc or bcs, not every instruction in an instruction set is used by a compiler, the authors have their favorite ways of doing things and the first job of the compiler is a functional equivalent.  The optimizer likewise has to be functionally equivalent first, then maybe more efficient second.

OMG, okay, so I never use godbolt, and I did not see the right combinations (cortex-m), but I tried clang for armv6m and...well...they unrolled the loop for speed. with -O3

clang with -O2

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   2220        movs    r2, #32
   2:   e003        b.n c <fun+0xc>
   4:   1e52        subs    r2, r2, #1
   6:   0840        lsrs    r0, r0, #1
   8:   2a00        cmp r2, #0
   a:   d003        beq.n   14 <fun+0x14>
   c:   07c3        lsls    r3, r0, #31
   e:   d0f9        beq.n   4 <fun+0x4>
  10:   0089        lsls    r1, r1, #2
  12:   e7f7        b.n 4 <fun+0x4>
  14:   4608        mov r0, r1
  16:   4770        bx  lr
```

and that is a whole other approach, you incur a lot of branches and the side effects of that (the cortex-m0+ pipe is tiny though).  This could perform worse not just because of pipe stuff but because of fetching, you would need a three deep branch predictor cache, but you incur extra fetching.  This is assumed to be an MCU running out of flash, and flash tends to be slow, depends heavily on the chip vendor and how fast you are running the mcu, etc.  More instructions may be much faster than less instructions with more branches.

With these high performance architectures (arm, risc) you need to also take into account alignment, take the same machine code adjust it up or down one or two or three half words and it can perform tens of a percent slower (or faster) simply due to fetching.  Running this code from ram instead of flash should help in general, but it depends on the chip vendor (arm is not a chip vendor) and how you are clocking things.

Comment: the above was with gcc 9.x.x and 10.x.x and clang from llvm 11.x.x  I have the newer gnu and llvm just not handy...

Comment: gcc 4.x.x is not any better (build for -mthumb not -march=armv6-m of course) I dont have a gcc 5 handy, would have to build one perhaps (on an older distro of course), but have spent enough time on this one already

Comment: If your overall function and what is in the if tmp & 1 is such that there is no spare register to store the #1 outside the loop, then of course because of the instruction set and that you asked it to do an AND, it is likely going to do the extra instruction, mov rx,#1 tst rx,ry bne

Comment: llvm and gcc are open source you are always welcome to add this corner case.  betware, both are held together with duct tape and bailing wire, once you look inside you may wish you had not...

Comment: Thanks for the detaild answer. Obviously I don't just want to count bits - there are better agorithms for that - but I at the current time I can't post the full code for licensing reasons. The function is small enough to fit into the cache, placing it into RAM only reduces the execution time by about 1%. In the meantime I did manage to get some assembler code working with a 15% speedup with the branch-on-carry alone. I'll post my solution in an hour or two, I want to test a few other things first.

Comment: fully understand.  the cortex-m0+ does not have a cache.  the chip might have flash cache thing with a fancy name (stm32's for example), granted you might have one with some other form of cache.

Comment: try adding nops, one at a time to the bootstrap or anywhere in front of this to change the alignment of the loop(s).

Comment: The SAML21 has no cache in the core, true, but the embedded flash controller has a 64 line 64bit direct mapped cache. I did try changing the alignment and could not measure a difference.

Comment: The Godbolt compiler explorer just gives you a GCC command line.  `-O3 -mcpu=cortex-m0` works there just like normal.